# How to sell Ethereum?

Tags: myetherwallet

I have a wallet on [myetherwallet.com](http://www.myetherwallet.com) with some Ethereum in it.

What's the best safe and easy way to sell these tokens?
Coinbase is irrelevant in my country.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a way to sell BTC you could do https://shapeshift.io/ to BTC

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to exchange in https://poloniex.com between other currencies like bitcoin and sell that in many sites like https://localbitcoins.com or many othere that you can find on google.